# Angular 10 - Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'select'

Tags: html, angular, angular-directive, angular-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I tried to start a new project on angular 10 today, but i got this problem whenever a try to use a ngModel inside of anything, and i know that question was already asked and resolved several times here on stackoverflow, but i already imported FormsModule and even ReactivFormsModule, but the error keeps happening

html

```
<div class="background">
    <h4>Character Selector</h4>
    <label>Character</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedChar" name="char-selector">
    <option *ngFor="let char of characterList" [value]="char.value">
      {{char.label}}
    </option>
  </select>
    <p> Selected Character: {{selectedChar}} </p>
</div>
```

modules.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ykpymn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Edit:** Declaring AppComponent solved the problem

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Here I am doing a two way binding with a `<select>` element and a `<p>` element, using the `ngModel` directive.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedChar">
    <option value="">-- Select a Value --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let char of characterList" [(ngValue)]="char.value">{{char.label}}</option>
</select>

<p>Selected Character: {{selectedChar}}</p>
```